# Field accessibility in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How to make a field must be read only on the GUI but able to edit via API in Salesforce?

Your suggestions Pls

Answer (score 4):

Just mark it as readonly on all page layouts for given object. And make sure it's not marked as required on the field itself (you can do it for example on text fields).

Some user Profiles will still bypass this page layout setting. Check which users have "Modify all data" checkbox ticked (by default all System Administrators) and whether you have some power users that would have "Modify All" on the object itself. This can be set on Profiles or via permission sets. More info - [in SF help](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_fieldaccess.htm).